# telnet usage in qtp?

Tags: qtp

how to use telnet in qtp.
tips n tricks on telnet using descriptive programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like [SystemUtil.Run, InvokeApplication or shell to something like vbscript](http://www.learnqtp.com/ways-to-launch-your-application/)

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Internet
Explorer\iexplore.exe","","C:\Documents and Settings\MyDir","open"

InvokeApplication "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.yahoo.com"
```

Comment: if i want get particular text in telnet window,if telnet screen has some words are there, i want particular string date or etc

Comment: You will have to either have to open a socket and talk telent, or you you could screen scrape the text